# Can I re-use pins that are labeled as the same physical STM32G4 Nucleo pin?

Tags: stm32, stm32cubemx

Poorly written question. Let me elaborate.

The Nucleo-32 board I'm developing (STM32G431KB) in STM32CubeIDE shows on the CubeMX "pinout view" that there are 4 distinct pins `PA6`, `PA15`, `PA5`, and `PB7`, each with their own *unique* set of alternate functions. I assigned a function to each of those pins (although you don't see `PB7` or `PA15` populated in this image for reasons discussed below):
[image]

---

So after configuring my peripherals, I then went about wiring the board according to the ST User Manual. That's when I realized `PA6/PA15` and `PA5/PB7` are both assigned to a single pin for each pair (header `CN3`, pins `7` and `8`):
[image]

---

My question is thus: am I prohibited from using a pin if I am simultaneously using a completely separate pin on that same physical header pin? **For example, if I'm using alternate function `SPI1 SCK` on pin `PA5`, is there no possible way to use pin `PB7` for anything at all?** Or is there some sort of fancy GPIO muxing feature that I'm not aware of?

Comment: I would normally say that if the pins really are tied together, then no. But PB7 already has its own dedicated pins here must be something else going on the board like jumpers because it isn't in the MCU itself. Nucleo-32 boards have their schematics available.

Comment: If you are not planning to use Arduino, all pins are available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For example, if I'm using alternate function SPI1 SCK on pin PA5, is
>   there no possible way to use pin PB7 for anything at all?

Of course there is. Just remove solder bridges SB2 and SB3 and you'll have separate PA5/PA6 on pins 8/7 of CN3 and PB7/PB15 on pins 7/8 of CN4

[image]

Comment: Oh wow I feel just ...this made me realize that those pins are actually duplicated on CN3 and **also** available on CN4. I thought they were only present on CN3. Removed the jumpers!

Answer (score 2):

Please read the datasheet and the user manual. In general, you can definitely use it separately. In this particular board you have limitations. As this is made to be Arduino nano board compatible.

[image][image]

Comment: I completely overlooked the fact that PA15/PB7 were present on both CN3 **and** CN4! Definitely don't need the Nano compatibility, so I just removed the jumpers